# compute The horizontal absolute difference value of a pixel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

We have the test image with M rows and N columns as
f(x,y), for x∈ [1,M] and y∈ [1,N ]. The horizontal absolute
difference value of a pixel is defined by
D (x, y) = |f (x, y +1) − f (x, y −1)|.
need help in how to implement it in matlab

Answer (score 1):

This will generate same size matrix, that you need:

```
mat1 = [zeros(2,size(f,2)); f];% adds 2 rows of zeros to begining
mat2 = [f;zeros(2,size(f,2))]; %adds 2 row of zeros to the end
Dd = mat1-mat2;
D = Dd(2:((size(Dd,1)-1)),:);%crop Dd matrix to size(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
D = abs( f(1:end-1,:) - f(2:end,:) );
```

check out `diff` command as well. Note that `D` has 1 row less than `f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
aux = abs(diff(f,[],2));
D = max(aux(:,1:end-1), aux(:,2:end));
```

For example: given

```
f = [3 5 6 4
     2 5 4 3
     8 9 3 1];
```

the result is

```
>> D
D =
     2     2
     3     1
     6     6
```